# next.js api NextApiRequest interface redeclare

Tags: next.js

I want to define `NextApiRequest.body` as generic.

**next.d.ts**

```js
import type { NextApiRequest as _NextApiRequest } from 'next';

declare module 'next' {
  interface NextApiRequest<T = any> extends _NextApiRequest {
    body: T;
    foot: T; // for test
  }
}
```

**/pages/api/hello.ts**

```js
import type { NextApiRequest } from 'next';

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest<boolean>, res:any){
  // when I hover the mouse below codes, then I see these.
  console.log(req.body); // (property) NextApiRequest<boolean>.body: any
  console.log(req.foot); // (property) NextApiRequest<boolean>.foot: boolean
}
```

How can I redeclare `NextApiRequest` interface ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found one solution.

**next.d.ts**

```
import type { NextApiRequest } from 'next';

declare module 'next' {
  interface TypedNextApiRequest<T = any> extends NextApiRequest {
    body: T;
    foot: T; // for test
  }
}
```

I declare `TypedNextApiRequest` instead of `NExtApiRequest` and use it.